# How to asynchroniously load remote content with BigPipe & Lazy Builder

Tags: 8, ajax

I need to show volatile data from a remote JSON endpoint on some of my nodes. I know I could do this entirely with JS, but I hoped I can do the same with BigPipe & Lazy Builder, so I can use Twig to render the JSON data.

Editors can make minor adjustments to the query, so I've created I custom field and added the `#lazy_builder` in the formatter of my custom field:

```
class RoomRateFormatter extends FormatterBase {

  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $element = [];

    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      $element[$delta] = [
        '#lazy_builder' => [
          AjaxController::class . '::getRoomRates',
          [ $item->uri, $item->option1, $item->option2, $item->option3 ]
        ],
        '#create_placeholder' => TRUE,
      ];
    }
    return $element;
  }
}
```

My controller fetches the remote data and then should asynchroniously insert the data.

```
class AjaxController extends ControllerBase {

  public function getRoomRates($jsonEndpoint, $option1, $option2, $option3) {
    $json = dummy_get_json_content_with_guzzle($jsonEndpoint);
    // in the final product this should be build with a #theme rendering my $json data instead of a #markup
    $build = [
      'json' => [
        '#markup' => '<p>Fetching data for ' . $jsonEndpoint .'</p><pre>' . json_encode(json_decode($json), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . '</pre>'
      ],
      '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0]
    ];
    return $build;
  }
}
```

The callback works, but my page loading is not progressive at all. It takes ~10sec (because of the remote JSON) and then comes with a single big flash. In all the BigPipe demo videos, the page is almost instantly rendered, with uncacheable parts updated afterwards. Without the field my pages renders in about one second. What am I missing to get the asynchronious, progressive page rendering?

Comment: the lazy builder doesn't qualify for autoplaceholdering, you can add `'#create_placeholder' => TRUE,` to $element[$delta] to enforce this

Comment: I've already tried this, and updated my question's code. It does change the rendering behaviour, but not as excepted. I can see from the browser's scrollbar that there is something added later on, but time to first byte is still > 10sec (which certainly is caused by my JSON request, as the page without this field loads in 1-2sec).

Comment: Is using the lazy builder feasible for asynchronious loading at all? I initially thought the lazy loader would do async JS to fetch render arrays or something similar. But with the placeholder active, I still don't see any XHR traffic, instead it just writes the content as script at the very end of the page. In my case this still leads to very high TTFB, because my slow `AjaxController::getRoomRates`is still done synchroniously.

Comment: This should work. Are you sure you have BigPipe enabled? Look at the end of the html source in the browser, there should be at least the lazy builder for the status message, and if you put `sleep(10);` in `StatusMessages::renderMessages` you should see the delay.

Comment: BigPipe, Internal Dynamic Page Cache and Internal Page Cache are all enabled. I do see the JS code for the BigPipe placeholder replacements as expected. The unexpected thing is that all the BigPipe content is included in a script on the main page request as well, and not in a separate ajax request.

Comment: This is normal, they are executed in a single stream. But you should see the page and be able to interact with it before the content of the lazy builders is delivered

Comment: Hm, it simply does not work as I hoped. I can clearly see in the browser and in the generated markup that BigPipe does replace the content at the very end of the page load, BUT... the lazy builder callback is very obviously executed before any rendering starts. Could it be that the callback is not "lazy" anymore when it is in the `content` region in a node's field?

Comment: Exactly, the whole point of bigpipe is that it does *not* result in additional requests. It could be that is a problem with your hosting infrastructure, if there is a proxy or webserver inbetween that does not support streaming the response through as it happens then it won't work. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/bigpipe/bigpipe-environment-requirements.

Comment: Also note that it does not work for anonymous users in core, only if authenticated. See https://www.drupal.org/project/big_pipe_sessionless